# understanding fair locks in java multhreading

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to understand fair locks in java and I have executed an implementation from

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/starvation-and-fairness.html

Which works fine

Code is Given Below

```
public class FairLock 
{
    private boolean           isLocked       = false;
    private Thread            lockingThread  = null;
    private List<QueueObject> waitingThreads =
            new ArrayList<QueueObject>();

  public void lock() throws InterruptedException
  {
    QueueObject queueObject           = new QueueObject();
    boolean     isLockedForThisThread = true;
    synchronized(this){waitingThreads.add(queueObject);}

    while(isLockedForThisThread)
    {
     synchronized(this)
     {
      isLockedForThisThread =
      isLocked || waitingThreads.get(0) != queueObject;
      if(!isLockedForThisThread)
      {
       isLocked = true;
       waitingThreads.remove(queueObject);
       lockingThread = Thread.currentThread();
       return;
     }
  }

  try{queueObject.doWait();}
  catch(InterruptedException e)
  {
    synchronized(this) { waitingThreads.remove(queueObject); }
    throw e;
  }
}
 }

  public synchronized void unlock()
  {
    if(this.lockingThread != Thread.currentThread())
    {
      throw new IllegalMonitorStateException(
        "Calling thread has not locked this lock");
    }

    isLocked      = false;
    lockingThread = null;

    if(waitingThreads.size() > 0){waitingThreads.get(0).doNotify();}
  }
}
```

Code For Queue Object

```
public class QueueObject 
{

  private boolean isNotified = false;

  public synchronized void doWait() throws InterruptedException
  {
   while(!isNotified){this.wait();}
   this.isNotified = false;
  }

  public synchronized void doNotify() 
  {
    this.isNotified = true;
    this.notify();
  }

  public boolean equals(Object o){return this == o;}
}
```

I understand most part of it but I have 2 doubts

1)
In This Line Of Code

```
   isLockedForThisThread =
   isLocked || waitingThreads.get(0) != queueObject;
```

What is This Part For?

```
waitingThreads.get(0) != queueObject;
```

What does it do? Cause I removed this part of code and I get the same correct results.

2)Since I believed I didn't need that part of code I changed my lock() method into my version given below.

```
public void myLock() throws InterruptedException
{
    QueueObject queueObject= new QueueObject();
    synchronized(this){waitingThreads.add(queueObject);}

    while(true)
    {
      synchronized(this)
      {
       if(!isLocked)
       {
        isLocked = true;
        waitingThreads.remove(queueObject);
        lockingThread = Thread.currentThread();
        return;
       }
     }

     try{queueObject.doWait();}
     catch(InterruptedException e)
     {
       synchronized(this){waitingThreads.remove(queueObject);}
       throw e;
     }
   }
```

Which Also gives me the right results, but I believe i haven't explored all the cases and this would fail in some situation which I would like an expert opinion on basically

.Where Would This Work?

.Where Would It Fail?

I am new to multithreading and basically looking for some explanation(in part 1) and feedback(in part 2) of my questions

Thank You

Comment: Not using a fair lock doesn't guarantee poor behavior, it just means that you're not guaranteed fairness. Presumably that condition is what ensures FIFO behavior on lock attempts.

Comment: a fair lock will try to give access to the thread waiting the longest. That's the only difference; a timestamp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice this line

```
synchronized(this){waitingThreads.add(queueObject);}
```

Here we are adding the newly created queue object to our queue but we are doing it in a synchronized way because 2 threads could be trying to add an object to the list at the same time. With that in mind lets move to the next synchronized block

```
isLockedForThisThread =
  isLocked || waitingThreads.get(0) != queueObject;
```

Now this thread would be locked if some other one is running which would ideally set isLocked to true so your question is why we are also doing waitingThreads.get(0) != queueObject. Imagine in the previous block thread A added an object to the queue just before thread B it is own this would give priority for A to run first, now it is possible that thread A gets suspended or something and thread B reaches the second synchronized block first, lets examine what we have now:
1. isLocked is false since no thread set it to true yet
2. A is first in the queue followed by B
3. Thread B is running while thread A is suspended

Now if you do what you did and remove the second part of the || B will think that it is its turn to take the lock and will go into the next 'if' statement which is not the correct behavior to have since the below line will remove the second element of the queue (in our example, it could be 3rd or even more in other cases) instead of the head element.

```
waitingThreads.remove(queueObject);
```

I am not an expert by any mean but this is the problem I see, hope I have helped it can be tricky to clearly explain multithreaded behavior using only text :P

Comment: I understand now. So what ur trying to say is that waitingThreads.get(0) != queueObject ensures that only the thread that got to this lock first has the right to lock this lock. Or basically if A was first in line and had to leave(or suspended in some case) when  it came back its place was reserved even if B,C,D,... etc all entered the que right? That makes perfect sense Thank U.

Comment: Also just being curious is there a way to make this lock re entrant? And is this the best implementation of fair lock out there? I don't want to feel like I am missing out that's all :P

Comment: And also why are we making unlock() method synchronized? I mean if only one thread is going to enter the critical section when it passes through lock() method then only one Thread will ever call unlock() right?